# Odd List behavior in Python: Empty list has items

Tags: python, list, loops, set

i have the following code:

```
def ViCYK(grammar, sentenceToParse):
    treeChart = []
    probChart = []

    for i in range(0,len(sentenceToParse)):
            row = []
            for j in range(0,len(sentenceToParse)):
                        row.append(set())
            treeChart.append(row)
            probChart.append(row)


    for i in range(0,len(sentenceToParse)):
            for rule in grm.rules_right_to_left[(sentenceToParse[i],)]:
                    treeChart[i][i+1].add(rule)



    print 't ', treeChart
    print 'p ', probChart
```

let `grm.rules_left_to_right` be an dictionary containing some rules.

My assumed output would be, that the `list` `treeChart` does now contain some filled `sets`, where as the the `sets` in `probChart` remain empty, because I did not fill them in the second loop.

In contrast, the output looks as follows:

```
>>> ViCYK(grm, ['The','The'])
t  [[set(['ART']), set([])], [set([]), set(['ART'])]]
p  [[set(['ART']), set([])], [set([]), set(['ART'])]]
```

Can anyone help or explain? I'm afraid the solution is very obvious, but I just can not see it.

Thanks,

b

Comment: You add rows to both in the first loop

Comment: `row` is **one list**. You have two references to that same list. Create copies instead.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I want to add rows to both lists in the first loop. Its the second loop where i just want to add to one of them